# AsyncHttpClient is not calling my POST API

Tags: android, asynchttpclient, android-async-http

I'm new to Android, I'm using `AsyncHttpClient` to call a POST API. But the API is not even being called

Below is my code:

```
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.addHeader("Key","random-key");
        JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
        body.put("clientId","random-client-id");
        body.put("question",question);
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(body.toString());
        client.post( getApplicationContext(),"http://localhost:3000/api/Chats/GetAnswer", entity,"application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                List<List<Answer>> answers = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    JSONArray answersJson = response.getJSONArray("answers");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable error) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to get answers for the question sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    `
```

Any hints of what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: What do you mean by "not even being called"

Comment: I mean that the Code in the API is not being hit (executed)

Comment: is the code called in debug mode ?.

Comment: Yes I've tried it in both release and debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it appear that the problem was in `AndroidManifest.xml` Since I'm using the internet and calling an external API, I had to add:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

And another thing. When working locally and testing using the emulator, we should write
`http://10.0.2.2:port-number/` instead of `http://localhost:port-number/`. Because android emulator runs in a virtual machine. Therefore, `localhost` will be emulator's own loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

Please put debugger at your method and  Make sure its calling or not , I think you have passed wrong context value  And as my point of View its better to User Retrofit than AsyncHttpClient.
Use Retrofit if you are communicating with a Web service.

Comment: I've used a debugger, but my API is not being called. And thank you for your Retrofit hint. I'll try it out if no solution was found for this problem.